# Android test orchestrator failing in multi-module project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, testing

I followed the documentation for the android test orchestrator and when I apply the following:

```
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
```

I get the following error

```
Not all files in androidTestUtil configuration are APKs: ...
Affected Modules: (all the modules in my app are listed here)
```

Its hard to find the documentation behind `androidTestUtil` and I am wondering if there any extra steps necessary to make the Android test orchestrator work in my project

Comment: It seems that the orchestrator is activated on _all_ modules in your project, and some of these modules are not Android project (e.g. pure Java or Kotlin project?).

Comment: No, all of my modules use the android library plugin except for top level application module.

However, the only difference is that we are using kotlin script gradle files, although, I don't see why it would fail under these circumstances either.

Comment: hey, did you find any resolution to the issue? Seeing the same issue using Kotlin DSL